# 2 different table models for DVD rental database

Tags: database, oracle

Hi I and my friend can't agree which model of database for DVD rental is better.
This is my model.

```
        Table: Rent

        NAME                        TYPE
        ID_Rent                     Integer ( Primary key )
        ID_Customer                 Integer ( foregin key from Customer )
        ID_office                   Integer ( foreign key from office )
        Date of Rent                DateTime
        Date of Returning           DateTime
        Possibly_penalty_in_euros   Integer

        Table : Rented_DVD
        NAME                        TYPE
        ID_Rented_DVD               Integer ( Primary key )
        ID_DVD                      Integer ( foreign key from DVD table )
        ID_Rent                     Integer ( foreign key from Rent )
```

This is his model

```
        Table: Rent

        NAME                        TYPE
        ID_Rent                     Integer ( Primary key )
        ID_Customer                 Integer ( foreign key from Customer )
        ID_DVD                      Integer ( foreign key from DVD table )
        ID_office                   Integer ( foreign key from office )
        Date of Rent                DateTime
        Date of Returning           DateTime
        Possibly_penalty_in_euros   Integer
```

And my Question is... Which model is better? Among these two tables we have fields for customer, for office, for dvd but they are not important. It is about what if someone comes into our office and will rent for example 4 DVDs at the same time.

In my case, I'll make 1 row into table Rent and 4 into table Rented_DVD. It will consume 78 bytes of space. 3 integers in Rented_DVD * 4 rows * 4 bytes + 4 Integers * 4 bytes + 2 DateTime * 7 bytes = 78 bytes of space.

My friend will make 4 rows into Rent table and he will consume 136 bytes of space ( 5 Integers * 4 Bytes + 2 DateTime * 7 Bytes ) * 4 rows = 136 Bytes of space.

So does it mean that my model is better than his? Respectively does his model consume more data space than mine or did I calculate it wrong?

Comment: @BobJarvis A) That is what "flag with custom reason" is for when the target site does not appear in the list B) No it doesn't belong on Code Review. This is database-model-review, not code-review. C) Vote to close because it is off-topic for Stack Overflow, not because it belongs somewhere else.

Comment: Return date (and penalties?) on your model should be moved to the rented table as well if you want to allow returning different dvds on different days.

Comment: make: `Date of Rent` and `Date of Returning` consistent with your other columns using underscores and make them: `Date_of_Rent` and `Date_of_Returning`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your concerns about storage space are *that* significant, considering modern databases can easily contain terabytes worth of data.

---

Rather, I think you should worry more about consistency and proper normalization. In that regards, I think your model is better. You have one unique `ID_Rent` for each rental transaction, and then transaction details in `Rented_DVD`. That is a more typical way of normalizing this type of data in real business setting. It's basically an `Invoice Header -> Invoice Detail` setup which is generally preferable to a "flat" `Invoice Header+Detail` table model.

Here are some more details explaining why this is generally so:

1) Avoiding duplication of data, e.g., customer IDs, rental IDs, dates, etc.

2) Easier to enforce unique keys, e.g., you can know *for sure* that you have one and only one `ID_Rental` for each transaction, so you can use a unique constraint on that field.

The only thing that makes it slightly more complex to use is that you need an additional join in your queries if both the header and detail information is needed, but that's a pretty trivial thing compared to having an efficient database layout.

Comment: But at the time DVD rental was something you could make money from, storage was expensive... ;-)